# React js - fetch API - TypeError: ticker.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to get fetch data from [here](https://vip.bitcoin.co.id/api/btc_idr/ticker) and showing it to my page using react.js, but I have an error when try to run the code, error shown:

> "TypeError: ticker.map is not a function".

This is my code:

```
class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    error: null,
    isLoaded: false,
    ticker: []
  };
}
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("https://vip.bitcoin.co.id/api/btc_idr/ticker")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          ticker: result.ticker
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          error
        });
      }
    )
}
render() {
  const { error, isLoaded, ticker } = this.state;
  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <ul>
        {ticker.map(item => (
          <li key={item.name}>
            {item.high} {item.low}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}}
```

Comment: If you do a console.log() of ticker can you check if it's an array or an object? Maybe you're traying to do a map function over an object, which won't work.

Comment: According to your link, ticker is an object. Object doesn't have `map` method

Comment: I used reactjs documentation for that code.
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#how-can-i-make-an-ajax-call

Comment: Can you show me the code to show data from object without map?
I'm already search for many fetch api using react js but all code always using 'map'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://vip.bitcoin.co.id/api/btc_idr/ticker is returning a json object and not an array.

```
{
    "ticker": {
        "high": "154922000",
        "low": "148658000",
        "vol_btc": "479.49235295",
        "vol_idr": "72668242553",
        "last": "148659000",
        "buy": "148657000",
        "sell": "148659000",
        "server_time": 1517320859
    }
}
```

Now, you can not call a `map` function on an object. That is why you are getting

> "TypeError: ticker.map is not a function"

So, first thing you can do is change your state like follows so that ticker is an empty object and not an array -

```
this.state = {
    error: null,
    isLoaded: false,
    ticker: {}
  };
```

And since its just one object and not an array, you can change the markup as follows -

```
<ul>   
  <li>{this.state.ticker.high} {this.state.ticker.low}</li>
</ul>
```

Note that the ticker object in the state is empty until you fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

Ticker returned from the API is an object, not an array and you are trying to map an object, which is is giving you an error. Are you trying to add objects to your array or just having one object. Here is the line that I am talking about:

```
this.setState({
    isLoaded: true,
    ticker: result.ticker
});
```

If you need a single object, remove the map function and just use (render):

```
 <li key={ticker.name}>{ticker.high} {ticker.low}</li>
```

However, if you want to keep adding the objects to your array, just do something like this (componentDidMount):

```
this.setState({
    isLoaded: true,
    ticker: [...this.state.ticker, result.ticker]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First push the new data into the state in the following manner

```
this.setState({
    isLoaded: true,
    ticker: [...this.state.ticker, result.ticker]
});
```

2) As it is asynchronous it may take time and data may not be available at that moment. So check the data in state before using map.

```
return (
      <ul>
        {ticker && ticker.length > 0 && ticker.map(item => (
          <li key={item.name}>
            {item.high} {item.low}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
```